# The meaning of theorem 9 (Set Theory and Metric Spaces - Kaplansky)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, order-theory

As I don't know what theorem 9 tries to say, I can't follow the highlighted statement in the proof of theorem 14. Could you please help explain theorem 9 in plain English to a layman like me, and why it leads to that statement *d* + *e* <= *e*?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial ordering is a binary relation which reflexive, anti-symmetric and transistive. What matters here is that it is anti-symmetric: if $e\leqq d+e$ and if $d+e\leqq d$, then $e=d+e$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Jose. I can see *e* <= *d* + *e* but how can *d* + *e* <= *e*?

Comment: Because $d\leqq e\implies d+e\leqq e+e=e$.

Comment: Oh, I see. The brief highlighted sentence of the proof threw me off as I thought it was a statement/given fact. Thank you! One more question: why is it called *partial*? What does *partial* refer to?

Comment: A "total" ordering is one in which any two different elements are comparable, and one of the two is better. A "partial" ordering is not so fussy. Among two elements, at most one is better, but it might also happen that the two elements can't be compared and we can't say which is better.

Comment: Thanks, @MJD. What I find difficult to understand set theory is that it often gives no example to abstract concepts, thus I can't visualise and remember their definitions. But theorem 9 talks about the relation <=, not elements, so how can a relation be partially ordering? Or does it mean we can't compare between *a* <= *b* and *d* <= *e*?

Comment: $\le$ for infinite cardinal numbers isn't the simple $\le$ that you already know from grade school. It has a very elaborate definition that is not at all obvious. You might guess that this new strange $\le$ will have properties similar to the old familiar $\le$, but until the proofs are supplied, you don't know for sure.

Comment: For an example of a relation that is a partial but not a total ordering, consider "divides" for integers. We know that $2$ divides $2,4,6,8\ldots$ and $3$ divides $3,6,9\ldots$. We can show that whenever $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $c$, then $a$ divides $c$ also. We can show that if $d$ divides $e$  and $e$ divides $d$ then $d$ and $e$ must be equal.  But not every two numbers are comparable in this way. $2$ doesn't divide $3$ and $3$ doesn't divide $2$.

Comment: Or consider this simpler example: restaurant A is better than restaurant B because at A you can get soup _and_ a sandwich for €1, but at restaurant B you get _only_ soup for €1.   At restaurant C you get _only_ a sandwich for €1. Clearly A is better than both B and C.  Is B better than C, or is C better than B?  We can't say for sure, it depends on how much you like soup!